# ezjail: update problems

Tags: freebsd, upgrade, jails

I'm having problems whenever I try to update my ezjail baseball on FreeSDB 10.

I'm on FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE-p11 and ezjail v3.4.2

The jails show the right version inside but the update progress doesn't seem to have finished.

This is what I'm getting:

```
ezjail-admin update -u
Looking up update.FreeBSD.org mirrors... 4 mirrors found.
Fetching metadata signature for 10.2-RELEASE from update6.freebsd.org... done.
Fetching metadata index... done.
Inspecting system... done.
Preparing to download files... done.

No updates needed to update system to 10.2-RELEASE-p11.
No updates are available to install.
Run '/usr/sbin/freebsd-update fetch' first.
Looking up update.FreeBSD.org mirrors... 4 mirrors found.
Fetching metadata signature for 10.2-RELEASE from update3.freebsd.org... done.
Fetching metadata index... done.
Inspecting system... done.
Preparing to download files... done.

The following files will be added as part of updating to 10.2-RELEASE-p11:
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/include/ntp_keyacc.h
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/include/rc_cmdlength.h
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/include/safecast.h
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/libntp/is_ip_address.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/sntp/m4/ntp_problemtests.m4
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/sntp/tests/fileHandlingTest.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/sntp/tests/run-t-log.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/sntp/tests/sntptest.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/sntp/tests/t-log.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/sntp/unity/auto/parseOutput.rb
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/sntp/unity/auto/type_sanitizer.rb
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/sntp/unity/auto/unity_test_summary.py
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/sntp/unity/unity_config.h
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/libntp/lfptest.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/libntp/sockaddrtest.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/leapsec.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/ntp_prio_q.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/ntp_restrict.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/rc_cmdlength.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/run-leapsec.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/run-ntp_prio_q.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/run-ntp_restrict.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/run-rc_cmdlength.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/run-t-ntp_scanner.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/run-t-ntp_signd.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/t-ntp_scanner.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpd/t-ntp_signd.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpq
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpq/Makefile.am
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpq/Makefile.in
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpq/run-t-ntpq.c
/usr/src/contrib/ntp/tests/ntpq/t-ntpq.c
Installing updates...mkdir: /usr/jails/newjail//boot: No such file or directory
mtree: /usr/jails/newjail//boot/kernel: No such file or directory
mtree: /usr/jails/newjail//boot/kernel.old: No such file or directory
touch: /usr/jails/newjail//boot/kernel.old/.freebsd-update: No such file or directory
Could not create kernel backup directory
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying to work this out at the moment as well. So far I've found [this post](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/ezjail-admin-update-u-lib32-errors.49672/) on the FreeBSD forums which have lead me to try

```
mkdir /basejail
mount -t nullfs -o rw /usr/jails/basejail /basejail
```

which allows the `/usr/jails/newjail` which is being updated to find the paths such as boot, etc and others and update them. So you can then run

```
ezjail-admin update -u
```

don't forget to unmount and remove the /basejail folder after you're updated.

Seems you can also run

```
ezjail-admin install
```

to re-create the basejail and it looks like that seems to work as well, though takes longer.

Comment: but would you do the `ezjail-admin install`also only after the null mount or without it?

Comment: After trying to upgrade the basejail from FreeBSD 11 to 12 using `ezjail-admin update` it was left in an unusable state, and even `ezjail-admin install` couldn't fix it. But after I rolled back the basejail filesystem using ZFS to the state *before* failed upgrade was started, the `ezjail-admin install` command worked fine, and now my basejail is fresh. So install is the way to go, upgrade is slower and just isn't worth it for the basejail. Maybe this helps someone.